# Reading arguments as Integer for a Bounty in a Bukkit plugin

Tags: java, minecraft, bukkit

This is just the start of the plugin and there will be more. This is what I want to have: For `/bounty <name> <amount>` I want to be able to read what is read on the amount to make a variable like `int a = args[1]`, but I don't know how to do that.

I have tried and it gave me some errors. I also want it so it can only be a number on the command. I am using bukkit version: craftbukkit-1.7.10-R0.1-20140804.183445-7

Here is my code:

```
public class Main extends JavaPlugin {

    public void onEnable() {
        Bukkit.getServer().getLogger().info("[Bounty] Enabled");
        Bukkit.getServer().getLogger().info("[Bounty] Developed by ITaco_v2");
    }

    public void onDisable() {
        Bukkit.getServer().getLogger().info("[Bounty] Disabled");
    }

    public boolean onCommand(CommandSender sender, Command cmd, String commandLabel, String[] args) {

        if ( !(sender instanceof Player)) {
            sender.sendMessage(ChatColor.RED + "[" + ChatColor.GREEN + "Bounty" + ChatColor.RED + "] " + ChatColor.GOLD + "In game use only!");
            return true;
        }

        if (cmd.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("bounty")) {
            if (sender.hasPermission("bounty.setbounty"));

            if (args.length == 0) {
                sender.sendMessage(ChatColor.RED + "Please specify a Player and a bounty amount.");
                sender.sendMessage(ChatColor.GREEN + "Like this: /bounty <playername> <amount>");
                return true;

            }

            Player target = Bukkit.getServer().getPlayer(args[0]);

            if (target == null) {
                sender.sendMessage(ChatColor.RED + "Could not find player!");
                return true;
            }

            if (target != null) {
                sender.sendMessage(ChatColor.RED + "Please specify a bounty amount.");
                sender.sendMessage(ChatColor.GREEN + "Like this: /bounty " + args[0] + " <amount>");
                return true;

            }

        }
        return false;
    }

}
```

Comment: Random pointer: can you store a reference to `Bukkit.getServer().getLogger()`?  Might make your logging process much easier. :)

Comment: Also, don't suppress deprecation warnings.  APIs are deprecated for a reason.  And there's no point in making the `Player` variable `final`.  It loses scope as soon as the method returns and becomes eligible for garbage collection, so you're just forcing the JVM to allocate space in permgen for no reason.

Comment: `its given me some errors` Please include them in your post, and what version of Bukkit are you using?

Comment: @MrLore That code hasnt given me any errors

Comment: You don't need the `if` statement at line 26.

Answer (score 1):

You can parse integer from string using [`Integer.parseInt(String)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt%28java.lang.String%29).

```
int bounty = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);
```

Comment: Please note that this will throw `NumberFormatException`.

Answer (score 1):

Before the actual codework, you should review the following code snippets from your code:

```
if (sender.hasPermission("bounty.setbounty"));
    // This code does nothing, perhaps you meant to return if not true?
if ( !sender.hasPermission("bounty.setbounty"))
    return true;
```

```
if (target == null) {
    // ...
}
/* This should be changed to "else"?
 * Or you should actually remove this (if statement),
 * it will never fail as target == null block terminates with "return true;"
 */
if (target != null) {
    // ...
}
```

---

I'll extend upon your existing code. Firstly, make sure there is a 2nd argument:

```
{
    //  }
        if (args.length == 1) sender.sendMessage(NOT_ENOUGH_ARGUMENTS);
        // ...
    }
    return false;
}
```

Then validate if it is an `Integer`:

```
{
    //  }
        if (args.length == 1)
            sender.sendMessage(NOT_ENOUGH_ARGUMENTS);
        else if ( !args[1].matches("-?\\d+"))
            // ** To not allow negative integers, remove '-?' **
            sender.sendMessage(NOT_INTEGER);
    }
    return false;
}
```

Then parse it with `Integer.parseInt()` and use it!

```
{
    //  }
        if (args.length == 1)
            sender.sendMessage(NOT_ENOUGH_ARGUMENTS);
        else if ( !args[1].matches("-?\\d+"))
            // ** To not allow negative integers, remove '-?' **
            sender.sendMessage(NOT_INTEGER);
        else {
            int amount = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);
            // The rest is your job to finish...
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

**Read more:**

- [Minecraft Forge Making Custom Player Command Issues](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25207288/3622940)